# How do I check where to go next?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I've just started playing FF7 again after a near 1-year hiatus.   That said, my save file contains a fair bit amount of playthrough already, so I have no desire to restart, but I can't figure out where exactly I'm supposed to go, since I don't remember exactly what I finished.  Is there a way in-game to figure out where my next place to be is?

Comment: Not really, this game is from another generation. But knowing where your last save file location is might actually help, assuming you didn't back track when saving.

Comment: The only thing I can remember is going to Gold Saucer presumably to get Omnislash before I defeated any of the Weapons. That said I have no idea where to go since I have decided no longer to do that quest.

Comment: Sounds like you're close to the end. Your next stop is probably the northern crater, although I don't remember specifically at which point the optional Weapons appear.

Comment: @Mario if i recall correctly Emerald is available from the moment you have the Sub which i think is mid way Disk 2 (you get the sub when going after the Huge Materia), Ultimate i think is Disk 3 and Ruby is after Ultimate

Comment: If you have the airship, you should be able to talk to someone inside to find out (e.g., Tifa, Cid, Barrett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specify an in-game way to know, I won't provide a comprehensive list of possible next locations. I will instead say that you should talk to your party members on the Highwind. (If fighting Weapons is an option then you certainly have it by now.) Most of the time at least one of them will give you a clue as to the next location, or even outright tell you where to go next.